# Will "standard" i386 release of Ubuntu work without any mods on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: system-installation

Can I install Ubuntu 12.04 on Raspberry Pi, model B? I need a small, cheap PC for XBMC media center and a browser to connect to my PC. I need a wifi, so I need at least 2 USB ports. I have set my eyes on Raspberry Pi, but not sure wheather it will provide. 
Please, provide any info on the topic, or alternatives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not at all. The Raspberry Pi is an ARM based computer, so you have to use a version of linux (and all software) specifically compiled for it.

In addition, the ARM instruction set is older than Ubuntu supports (see http://www.raspberrypi.org/faqs ), so you may have to use Debian which is similar to Ubuntu in the mean time.